# Blessing on an Aveira?

Tags: blessing

Would one make the birchas Ha'airusin and Sheva brachos if one was mesader kiddushin for a couple that were prohibited to marry by a negative prohibition in the Torah, but where kiddushin does take effect?

Comment: What G-d fearing person would agree to be mesader kiddushin in this case? Who is asking the question?

Comment: No, you don't make a *berachah* on a מצוה הבאה בעבירה.

Comment: anyone have a source?